# Cannot get my php script to execute from AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to create a registration form that checks to see if the user is already in the system by email using AJAX. I cannot seem to get my php file to run though and have tried a variety of items from the forums. Can anyone help with my code

the script is as follows.

```
<script>
function showUser() {
  var useremail = $('#useremail').val();
  var userpassword = $('#userpassword').val();
  var userzip = $('#userzipcode').val();
  var url = "/assets/php/userlogin/userdupcheck.php?e="+useremail+"&p="+userpassword+"&z="+userzip;

xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

The html form is

```
<div id="registration" title="Register at TownCaddy.com">
<form name="register" id="register" onsubmit="showUser()">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="useremail" name="useremail" type="text" placeholder="Your Email" size="20" maxlength="45" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="userpassword" name="userpassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" size="20" maxlength="32" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="userzipcode" name="userzipcode" type="text" placeholder="Zip" size="5" maxlength="5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</div>
```

and the PHP file userdupcheck.php code is below

```
<?php
$e = $_GET['e'];
$p = $_GET['p'];
$z = $_GET['z'];
$query_dupUserCheck = "SELECT tblUser.userKey FROM tblUser WHERE tblUser.useremail = '".$e."'";
$sqlsearch = mysql_query($query_dupUserCheck);
$resultcount = mysql_num_rows($sqlsearch);

if ($resultcount > 0) {
    print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    print 'alert("The email address '. $e.' is already registered")'; 
    print '</script>';
} else {
    require_once('register.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: What does Firebug show you?

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to be sending a password in a GET request. You should use post so the password isn't exposed in the url

Comment: Just a thought (not certain about this), but you aren't defining an 'action' attribute for your form tag. Since this is required, the behaviour could well be undefined if it is not present (such as not firing an onSubmit event, since without an action it has no meaning). http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

Comment: @Gus - HTML 5 makes it optional, and the data is being submitted with XHR, which bypasses the form submission process entirely anyway.

Comment: Mr. Martin I tried the post but did not get any results either

Comment: I am not getting any errors with Firebug anything in particular I should look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Why? I don't know.. I moved to jQuery before figuring this out long time ago. Try it this way

```
xmlHttp.open("GET", "test.php?e=test", false);
xmlHttp.send();
```

Also, why not save your self the time and move this over to using jQuery? Anyways.. I really don't know anything about x-www-for-urlencoded because I really only used it once.. but at least this should get you going. I have tested this my self a few min ago and it is working... here is my debug code..

```
<?php



$e = empty ($_GET['e'])?null:mysql_real_escape_string ($_GET['e']);
$p = empty ($_GET['p'])?null:mysql_real_escape_string ($_GET['p']);
//$z = $_GET['z'];


$name = "xlordt";
$rescount = null;

if (isSet ($_GET ['e']))
{

    echo $_GET ['e'];;
    exit; //exit else, we will get the page instead of results
}
//if ()
if ($rescount > 0) {

    print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
    print 'alert("The email address '. $q.' is already registered")'; 
    print '</script>';

} else {

    //require_once('register.php');
}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Nothing</title>
   <metha charset="utf-8" />
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
        function showUser() {
            var useremail = $('#useremail').val();
            var userpassword = $('#userpassword').val();
            var userzip = $('#userzipcode').val();
            var url = "test2.php";

            if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {     // for Forefox, IE7+, Opera, Safari, ...
                 xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }

            xmlHttp.open("GET", "test.php?e=test", false);
            xmlHttp.send();
            xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        }
   </script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <div id="registration" title="Register at TownCaddy.com">
    <form name="register" id="register" onsubmit="return showUser();">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="useremail" name="useremail" type="text" placeholder="Your Email" size="20" maxlength="45" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="userpassword" name="userpassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" size="20" maxlength="32" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input id="userzipcode" name="userzipcode" type="text" placeholder="Zip" size="5" maxlength="5" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Register" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
  </div>    
  </body></html>
```

Comment: I am still not able to get this to work. I copied and pasted the code you have into a new file and tested. Could there be something missing on my local machine or server?

Comment: How are you testing this? are you using firebug or similar to check the results?

Comment: I ran through firebug but did not see any errors. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Make sure "Persist" is on in the "Console" section and try again.

Comment: got it thank you. Let me play with it more to see if I can get it to execute my code now and get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: That worked Thank you so much. I do have another follow up though... I managed to get the PHP to check for existing user then if not found create the user in my database. How can I redirect to another page if it successfully enters the user, but stay on the same page if not? I tried the header("Location : ../../../index.php"); but did not work.